# {option_value} how to pull from database

Tags: cartthrob, database

I am very new to CartThrob and EE so excuse my ignorance.  I am charged with pulling order data from the database so I can write that data in our business system.

In the database we have stored, I believe, in {option_value} the item code for our inventory.  I have looked through all the fields in exp_channel_data for that information but can't seem to find it.

In EE, I go to CartThrob, Products, Store-Products.  Look at one of the products, under size options, there’s a field Option Short Name.  Where is that stored?

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out with field ID # corresponds to your Products > Size Options field. Then look that `field_id_XXX` column up in the `exp_channel_data` table. The data is store as a base64 encoded and serialized array, which is somewhat of a convention in EE. So, to decode it, you'd do:

```
$query = ee()->db->select('field_id_XXX')->where('entry_id', 'YYY')->get('channel_data');

$data = $query->row('field_id_XXX');

$data = unserialize(base64_decode($data));

foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $row['option_value'];//this is what you're looking for
}
```